# How to print more than one value from nested dict in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to parse output from Get API. My response text is:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
   "date_created": "22:20:47",
   "name": "test1",
   "id": "12345",
   "status": "0"
  },
  {
   "date_created": "00:09:17",
   "name": "test2",
   "id": "23456",
   "status": "0"
  },
  {
   "date_created": "00:08:02",
   "name": "test3",
   "id": "34567",
   "status": "0"
  },
```

I have ~100 ids. I need to print only ids and search for specific id from list.

so far, i parse with next method:

```
json_data = get_req.text
python_data = json.loads(json_data)
id = python_data["data"][0]["id"]
print "Object id: ", id
```

But it is printing only one ID, where i need all of them.

Do you have any ideas how can i print all of them?

Comment: You're only checking the first `dict`. Use a `for` loop to check all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a list of dicts so you need loop:

```
ids = [x.get('id') for x in python_data["data"]]
print (ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried your implementation and works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this below code snippet:

```
for i in range(len(python_data["data"])):
    print(python_data["data"][i]["id"])
```

I got the expected output :

```
12345
23456
34567
```